# Getting Current City's Country from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

FB graph api *seems to* always return "city, state" for USA fields of "current city" and "hometown", but *seems to* always return "city, country" for anything outside of the USA.

Is this a reliable assumption? Are there any other countries besides US that would return "city, state"? The FB Docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) don't explain this, and i'm kinda guessing my way around this.

Comment: Another bit of fun... sometimes Facebook returns "city, country" for non-US (like Paris, France), but other times it seems to return "district, city, country" (like shinjuku-ku,Tokyo,Japan). Ugh... just wrapped all my code in if loops with lookup against state name to determine foreign or not. Ain't pretty, but it works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the FQL and query the [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) table for the `current_location` field which would return a more comprehensive and well structured response:

```
SELECT current_location FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

You can try is in the Facebook Graph API explorer using the new [`fql`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me%28%29) end-point. Which would return something like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "current_location": {
        "resultType": {
          "fieldTypes": {
            "street": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "city": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "state": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "country": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "zip": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "latitude": {
              "min": null,
              "max": null,
              "strict": false
            },
            "longitude": {
              "min": null,
              "max": null,
              "strict": false
            },
            "id": {
              "min": null,
              "max": null,
              "strict": false
            },
            "name": {
              "strict": false
            }
          },
          "includeNullFields": false
        },
        "street": null,
        "city": "Beirut",
        "state": "Beyrouth",
        "country": "Lebanon",
        "zip": "",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "id": 106188806084417,
        "name": "Beirut, Lebanon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice the `city`,`state` and `country` fields are there along with the *inconsistent* `name` field.